# Mvc3 a potentially dangerous request.form ... Solution without disabling Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'd rather not disable validation on my form. I feel like I'm not taking advantage of MVC's benefits if I do that. Is there a way to regex the contents of a property submitted in a form before mvc gets its hands on it? I simply want to allow only alphanumerical values and some symbols but still leave protection on. Do I have to disable with [ValidateInput(false)]??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom validation attributes and apply them to your entire model class, or individual properties.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/21/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-i-server-code.aspx

Comment: Will this custom filter override or be applied before the other validation kicks in and triggers the exception? Again, I don't want to set [ValidateInput(false)]

Comment: It's order will depend on the level it is applied to - class/ property. For instance, if you have a Txtbox in your form that is for Username, and you'd want it to be: a required field, of at least 10 chars and consist of only vowels. You could use validation attr [Required] and [StringLength] that are supplied out of the box. For the vowel requirement you could write a custom validator that uses Regex and apply it to the Username property ... something like [OnlyVowels]. That way, all three validations will be enforced.
Read up on Data Annotations Validation.
Hope this helps, good luck!